# Is it possible to rename Geometry Nodes input attribute names?

Tags: geometry-nodes

When creating new inputs for a Geometry Nodes node tree you can change the name of each value. However I'd like to also change the attribute name(?) that shows up in the tooltip. In the example below the attribute name of the "Float" input is "Input_2". I'd like to change that.

[image: 1]

When animated, these attribute names are also used. As you can imagine this isn't very handy at all:

[image: 2]

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible and is really a pity. Maybe file a "bug/feature" request to Blender, because i think that makes sense.

Comment: Maybe fill the *Description* field of your attribute ? It doesn't solve your question, but when hovering the attribute in Modifiers tab, it will display the description. Could help you find what you want more quickly.

Comment: @Chris That's unfortunate but good to know, thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Lutzi In Blender 3.6 it was called "Tooltip" and it seems to be my best option still. For the example I entered "Float input." as the tooltip. Still, thanks for your suggestion.